# awk: print matching group from input

Tags: awk

I've got a log file in which I'm looking for a string `--location http://example.com/whatever` and I'm interested only in the URL. It's multiple lines of input and this *location* string is somewhere on one of the lines, I don't know which line and where on the line it is.

It's easy to print it with this `awk` script:

```
/--location ([^ ]+)/ {
   match($0, "--location ([^ ]+)", m);
   print m[1]
}
```

However as I'm already matching what I want in the `/--location .../` pattern it feels wrong to run the other `match()` with the very same pattern.

I wonder if it's possible to print the group match from the `/--location ([^ ]+)/` and get away without the `match()` call?

I'm using *gawk 3.1* if that matters

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
awk 'match($0, "--location ([^ ]+)", m) {print m[1]}' file
```

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
a b --location FindMe1 cde
a b --location
--location FindMe2 a b
```

Our command produces this output:

```
$ awk 'match($0, "--location ([^ ]+)", m) {print m[1]}' file
FindMe1
FindMe2
```

#### How it works

The expression `match($0, "--location ([^ ]+)", m)` returns true (1) if a match was found and false (0) if no match was found.  Thus it serves as a condition for the action `print m[1]`.  Consequently, the print only happens if the match was found.

Comment: Dang, I was just writing a comment to add "How it works". :) Nice solution, and nice answer.